# Can Scala string match { case regex(...) => ... } find multiple matches?

Tags: regex, scala

When I test this regex:  `\(\(([^)]*)\)\),?\s*`

against this string:

`((1.1 1.2, 1.3 1.4)), ((2.1 2.2, 2.3 2.4, 2.5 2.6))`

in RegexBuddy I get these matches:

```
* Match 1:  ((1.1 1.2, 1.3 1.4)), 
  Group 1:  1.1 1.2, 1.3 1.4
* Match 2:  ((2.1 2.2, 2.3 2.4, 2.5 2.6))
  Group 1:  2.1 2.2, 2.3 2.4, 2.5 2.6
```

When in Scala I try:

```
val rx = """\(\(([^)]*)\)\),?\s""".r
val s  = "((1.1 1.2, 1.3 1.4)), ((2.1 2.2, 2.3 2.4, 2.5 2.6))"

val a = s match {
  case rx(x) => "matches"
  case _     => "does not match"
}
val b = rx.findAllMatches(s)

// a is "does not match"
// b is List("((1.1 1.2, 1.3 1.4)), ", "((2.1 2.2, 2.3 2.4, 2.5 2.6))")
```

Is there a way, on the line with `rx(x)` above, that I could have gotten the multiple matches that `fillAllMatches` was able to give me?

Comment: When you use a regex with `match`, you only get the first match only. You need findAllIn or similar.